# Showing that $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} |a_n| / |a_{n+1}| = R$ implies that the radius of convergence of $\sum a_n z^n$ is also $R$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Hypothesis:** Suppose that $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} |a_n| / |a_{n+1}| = R$.

**Goal:** Show that $\sum a_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R$.

**Attempt:**

1. The radius of convergence of $\sum a_n z^n$ can be expressed as

   $$
   \frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}}
   $$
2. From this we can derive

   $$
   \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_n \right|^{1/n}} = \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_{n+1} \right|^{1/n}} = \left( \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_{n+1} \right|} \right)^{1/n} = \left( \frac{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup}|a_{n}|}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_{n+1} \right|/|a_{n}|} \right)^{1/n}
   $$

   so that then

   $$
   \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_n \right|^{1/n}} = \left( R \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} |a_{n}|} \right)^{1/n}
   $$

   But at this point I'm not sure what to make of this subresult.

Comment: You can't move the $n$-th root across the $\limsup$. The $n$ is bound in $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use d'Alembert rule:

Let $z\in\mathbb C$.

$$
\frac{|a_{n+1} z^{n+1}|}{|a_nz^n|} \to \frac{|z|}{R}
$$
so when $|z|<R$ there is convergence, and when $|z|>R$ there is divergence.

Hence, $R$ is the radius.

Comment: This is making use of the ratio test for real sequences, no?

Comment: @user125104 Absolute convergence implies convergence.